# How to remove/unimport inline CSS with Webpack?

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, inline-styles, webpack-style-loader

Ok, I have imported a css file with Webpack `style-loader` and `css-loader` like this:

```
import './style.css'
```

And Webpack append it to my page via `style` tag. So far, so good. But, when the state of application change, I want to remove this particular style. Of course, I could remove it with `document.querySelector('style')`, but is there some natural Webpack way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the purpose? Are you trying to replicate HMR functionality of Webpack dev server/middleware?

Comment: Every JS view has it own style. When I change the view, style from the previous view remains appended in the HTML.

Comment: @DamjanPavlica In that case you might not want a generic style-loader. You could use `css-loader` and put a `<style>` tag *inside* your view.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is a good idea to integrate with Webpack on that level. E.g. Angular 2 starter kit uses [to-string-loader with css-loader](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js#L153-L160) to make them inline styles (Angular 2 also uses shadow DOM to isolate view/component style).

Comment: psst, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334859/burninate-the-game-development-tag-again

Answer (score 2):

With style-loader, you could mark some of your css files lazy, and call `.use()` when mounting the route, and `.unuse()` when unmounting the route.

React hooks example:

```
import styles from './styles.lazy.css';

export function LegacyRoute() {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    styles.use();
    return () => { styles.unuse() };
  }, []);
  return <p>Hello World</p>;
}
```

webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        exclude: /\.lazy\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.lazy\.css$/i,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader', options: { injectType: 'lazyStyleTag' } },
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Source:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader#lazystyletag

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact answer to this question, but if you're looking for a create-react-app solution and can't edit the `webpack.config.json` take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67352039/5648839