# How to remove imported css in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, import, redux

I have used the following code to import css

```
componentWillMount() {
    import('./patient-summary.css');
}
```

How to remove imported css from react when component is not in use. When i go back to previous screen this css gets applied there. Any idea ?

**UPDATE:: Webpack config**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist')
},
module: {
  rules: [
      {
          test: /\.js?$/, 
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        loader: "file-loader"
      }
      ,
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: "file-loader"
      }
  ]
  },
  devServer: {
  contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
  historyApiFallback: true,
  port: 3000,
  watchOptions: {
    // Delay the rebuild after the first change
    aggregateTimeout: 300,

    // Poll using interval (in ms, accepts boolean too)
    poll: 1000,
  },
  },
  plugins: [
   // Ignore node_modules so CPU usage with poll
   // watching drops significantly.
   new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([
      path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
   ])
 ],
 };
```

Comment: Please post your webpack configurations. I think you concat all css files together.

Comment: why would you want to remove the imports. they will be in the local cache. let it be there

Comment: @M.R.Safari updated

Comment: So... I guess you haven't found any solution yet

Comment: @Denny I found it. To import all css files at top of the component. Atlast in webpack build all the css into a single file. So its not individual css files. Just one file

Comment: But that's not a solution to your question is it? To remove imported css. You are still loading everything

Comment: There is no way to remove an imported css. You can override with !important, or switch the entire HTML file

Answer (score 6):

I found a (sort of) reasonable way to do this in React. In short, you can [lazy-load React components](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) that contain the `import './style.css'`, and when it loads, you can capture the imported [StyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet) to toggle its [StyleSheet.disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet/disabled) property later.

Here's the main code, with more explanation below. Here's my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/arniebradfo/dc1dcb0793108cfc4cfca8faf0cb15d3).

#### `useDisableImportedStyles.tsx`

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

// global list of all the StyleSheets that are touched in useDisableImportedStyles
const switchableGlobalStyleSheets: StyleSheet[] = []

// just to clarify what createUseDisableImportedStyles() returns
type useDisableImportedStyles = () => void

export const createUseDisableImportedStyles = (
    immediatelyUnloadStyle: boolean = true
    // if true: immediately unloads the StyleSheet when the component is unmounted
    // if false: waits to unloads the StyleSheet until another instance of useDisableImportedStyles is called.This avoids a flash of unstyled content
): useDisableImportedStyles => {
    let localStyleSheet: StyleSheet
    return () => {
        useEffect(() => {

            // if there are no stylesheets, you did something wrong...
            if (document.styleSheets.length < 1) return

            // set the localStyleSheet if this is the first time this instance of this useEffect is called
            if (localStyleSheet == null) {
                localStyleSheet = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1]
                switchableGlobalStyleSheets.push(localStyleSheet)
            }

            // if we are switching StyleSheets, disable all switchableGlobalStyleSheets
            if (!immediatelyUnloadStyle) {
                switchableGlobalStyleSheets.forEach(styleSheet => styleSheet.disabled = true)
            }

            // enable our StyleSheet!
            localStyleSheet.disabled = false

            // if we are NOT switching StyleSheets, disable this StyleSheet when the component is unmounted
            if (immediatelyUnloadStyle) return () => {
                if (localStyleSheet != null) localStyleSheet.disabled = true
            }

        })
    }
}
```

**WARNING:** This is pretty finicky. You must set this up exactly or there may be unintended consequences

#### Conditions:

1. `createUseDisableImportedStyles` must called in global scope in the same tsx file as the imported css being targeted and the component to be lazy loaded

```
import React from 'react'
import { createUseDisableImportedStyles } from './useDisableImportedStyles'
import './global-styles.css'
const useDisableImportedStyles = createUseDisableImportedStyles()
export const CssComponent: React.FC<{}> = () => {
    useDisableImportedStyles()
    return null
}
export default CssComponent
```

2. A component using this hook *should* be lazy loaded:

```
LazyCssComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./cssComponent'))
...
<React.Suspense fallback={<></>}>
    {condition && <LazyCssComponent/>}
</React.Suspense>
```

3. An exception to lazy loading might be using this in a single, normal, non-lazy component so styles are loaded on first render

- NOTE: the `InitialCssComponent` never needs to actually render, it just needs to be imported
- BUT: this will only work if there is **one single** .css file imported globally, otherwise, I don't know what would happen

```
import InitialCssComponent  from './initialCssComponent'
LazyCssComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./cssComponent'))
//...
{false && <InitialCssComponent/>}
<React.Suspense fallback={<></>}>
    {condition && <LazyCssComponent/>}
</React.Suspense>
```

**GOOD LUCK!**

Comment: Works like a charm. I had to add a loop to select the first truly local stylesheet though, some google font import kept creeping to the end of document.styleSheets.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, AFAIK, you should not call any imports in componentWillMount. This means that every time a new component about to mount, this css will be loaded over and over. Instead, it must be placed at the beginning of your module.

The way that you avoid unnecessary css imports is to avoid unnecessary component imports. Hence, if your component is not called anywhere, then this css will not be loaded.

For routing, I think you will need to do some code splitting, but I am not sure if it is straightforward or the right way to do.

[Link 1](http://jonathancreamer.com/advanced-webpack-part-2-code-splitting/)
[Link 2](https://medium.com/@somebody32/how-to-split-your-apps-by-routes-with-webpack-36b7a8a6231)

Comment: How do we avoid importing modules since we want to route

Comment: I think you will need to do some code splitting, but I am not sure if it is straightforward or the right way to do. I added two links.

Comment: Thanks for the info . I have divided the code. But if once the css is added, if i go back to previous screen, its affected with css added later onwards

Comment: This is incorrect. Imports in ES6 (and webpack) are only loaded once. You can verify this yourself in the inspector. If there are multiple selectors, they will appear in the styles panel crossed out.