# Clear imported CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, antd

#### Context

I'm using React Router. Most of my routes/pages include some sort of .css for theirs components + the implicit `antd` (UI framework) stylesheet:

```
import '../styles.css';
```

This way all views declared in my App automatically inherit these stylesheets.

#### Question

I now need to have a route/page that starts off clean from any other stylesheet.

Is it possible to define that once the page component is rendered, any other stylesheet is removed from the rendered view?

---

#### What have I tried?

I tried removing the imports from up to the `<App>` component declaration (assuming `create-react-app` base). But each page component will clearly import those styles so when I import those components the `antd` styles are going to be imported too.

Not to mention that probably just the fact that `antd` is installed as an `npm` dependency probably includes those styles.

#### FAQ

> Why do you need this if all styles for each component are written independently from each other? Can't you just not render those components?

I'm not rendering those component. This is mainly a problem with `antd` default styling of the `body` and `font-family` and so on.

Comment: For the downvote and close vote due to "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." -- This question doesn't seek debugging help. It asks if there exists a functionality within react for this specific situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish that by using [style-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-it) package

**Component A**

```
class AppA extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Style>
          {`
            body {
              font-size: small;
              font-family: arial;
            }
            h1 {
              font-size: large;
              color: red
            }

         `}
        </Style>
        <h1> Component A this defualt style for h1 red</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Component B**

```
class AppB extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Style>
          {`
            body {
              font-size: small;
              font-family: arial;
              background: #f1f1f1;
            }
            h1 {
              font-size: large;
              color: blue
            }
         `}
        </Style>
        <h1> Component B this defualt style for h1 blue</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Working Example

[image: Edit xv40w9krnq]

Comment: not sure why you got downvoted, this is a decent answer. it's definitely not the only way to do it though

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to this specific question, but if you found this post (as i did) while looking for how to un-import a css file from a React app, theres a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67352039/5648839

For this specific question, I'd use [emotion's `<Global/>` Component](https://emotion.sh/docs/globals)

Answer (score -1):

You could use inline styles to style components independently. Even if various stylesheets are imported, you could do:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ font-family: 'sans-serif', color: 'red', padding: 10 }}>
        This will override imported styles.
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to hijack this comment, but the original comment you posted is on a closed question so cannot comment there (will delete this after you read it). is potrace still the best vectorization option you have used since 2017? thanks for your help!