# Is it possible to unload dynamic css imports in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have two files which i load with react.lazy and suspense:

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy }  from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
const MainLayout = lazy(()  => import('Components/Layout/MainLayout'))

export const PrivateRoute = () => (
  <Route  render={() => {
    return (
      localStorage.getItem('user')  != null// validation that it is a valid user
          ?
          <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>            
          <MainLayout/>
          </Suspense>
          : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login'}} />)
  }} />
)
```

Second:

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from "react";
const DefaultLayout = lazy(()  => import('Components/Layout/DefaultLayout'))

export const PublicRoute = () => (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>            
        <DefaultLayout/>
    </Suspense>
  )
```

the `/login` path is refrencing a component (login) that is inside of the 
DefaultLayout component.

**Scenario:**

When the user is not logged in I load the DefaultLayout component which in turn contains my login component which imports cssFile1.css.

When the user enters the credentials i forward them to a path that is contained in my PrivateRoute where in turn i have cssFile2.css

The problem here is that cssFile1.css was loaded when i was using the loginpage but when the user logs in i want to unload cssFile1.css, is this possible and if yes then how?

Comment: you can simply disable the sheet in `document.styleSheets`

Comment: @dandavis that does work but I'm not sure how youre supposed to figure out which style sheet is which, doesnt seem to be a way to set any attributes such as "title" in webpack. Maybe a dummy rule you could filter by. Inserting with css-loader via css-style-sheet option allows you to keep a js reference and that does work, just takes some webpack config

Comment: @light24bulbs: I've use smoking guns like `xxx { content: "here i am"; }` before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, then no, it's impossible, because of Webpack imported css when React compiled, anyway, you can try to `css in js` libs, such a [Aphrodite](https://github.com/Khan/aphrodite).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, This might not be the most optimum approach, but can't the whole CSS inside the `cssFile1.css`be scoped? As in all the rules are written targetting elements if they are inside a certain container with a class say 'cssFile1'.

Likewise the 2nd CSS file will target all the elements only if they are located inside a container with the class 'cssFile2'.

now all you have to do to "unload/switch" the css is changing the main container class and the respective CSS rules will apply.

One last tip is, if you are using SASS / LESS its just a matter of enclosing the rules inside a container and all the rules will be scoped upon compilation.

Comment: I am using SASS but for simplicity i said css1 and css2. i recently learned about lazy and suspense which I think are great and so I thought it would be great if I could also unload css files when they are no longer needed,

Answer (score 1):

I found a (sort of) reasonable way to do this in React. In short, you can [lazy-load React components](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) that contain the `import './style.css'`, and when it loads, you can capture the imported [StyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet) to toggle its [StyleSheet.disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet/disabled) property later.

[Here's my original solution to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67352039/5648839).

[Here's a Gist](https://gist.github.com/arniebradfo/dc1dcb0793108cfc4cfca8faf0cb15d3).

Comment: gist is down, great example of why its a good idea to put your answer in your answer

Comment: gist is fixed. sorry @light24bulbs

Answer (score 1):

As of late 2022, you can use the new CSSStyleSheet web API to control styles entirely from JS, including unloading. You can load this into a react app using css-in-js if you make a change to the css-loader options in webpack.

You can do things like

```
import darkStyles from '../scss/main/dark.css-style-sheet.scss';
import lightStyles from '../scss/main/light.css-style-sheet.scss';

// now mount one of those to the dom
document.adoptedStyleSheets = [darkStyles]
sheet.disabled = true;
```

It's a little involved for this answer, but I wrote a blog post about how to get it working with react: https://www.lunasec.io/docs/blog/css-style-sheets/

Basically, you need to use craco (or eject) to set up a new rule that sets `exportType: 'css-style-sheet'` on css-loader.